# UDK - changing game type problem

Tags: udk

I have made a small game for testing purposes and a packaged the game, and ran my game but when I run it, it runs with the UTdeathmatch type game.
and I made my `DefaultGame` to `DefaultGame=UDKBase.SimpleGame` but still I have a gun in my hand doesn't work How do i fix that?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which map are you running? The map can also specify which game type to use on it. Look at View->WorldProperties->Default Game Type. I think there's also a game type for Play In Editor mode.

The game type can also be overridden via command-line ("?game=").

Finally, after the engine determines which GameInfo to load, it calls `SetGameType()` on that GameInfo. This gives you the option of overriding your own game type based on map name, command-line options, etc. (see `UTGame::SetGameType()`) The default functionality is for the GameInfo to just return its own class, so this feature is entirely optional.